# How to implement Implication Free, NNF, DISTR functions for CNF?

Tags: c, string, algorithm, logic

**Algorithm 1: IMPL FREE(φ)**

*Input*: φ : a logic formula
*Output*: φ′: all implications ( Ô⇒ ) in φ′are removed and φ′ ≡ φ

`switch φ do
    case φ is a literal: do return φ;
    case φ is ¬φ1: do return ¬IMPL FREE(φ1);
    case φ is φ1 ∧ φ2: do return IMPL FREE(φ1) ∧ IMPL FREE(φ2);
    case φ is φ1 ∨ φ2: do return IMPL FREE(φ1) ∨ IMPL FREE(φ2); 
    case φ is φ1 Ô⇒ φ2: do return IMPL FREE(¬φ1 ∨ φ2);
    otherwise do assert(0);`

**Algorithm 2: NNF(φ)**

*Input*: φ : a logic formula without implication (=>)
*Output*: φ′: only propositional atoms in φ′are negated and φ′ ≡ φ

`switch φ do
    case φ is a literal: do return φ;
    case φ is ¬¬φ1: do return NNF(φ1);
    case φ is φ1 ∧ φ2: do return NNF(φ1) ∧ NNF(φ2);
    case φ is φ1 ∨ φ2: do return NNF(φ1) ∨ NNF(φ2);
    case φ is ¬(φ1 ∧ φ2): do return NNF(¬φ1 ∨ ¬φ2);
    case φ is ¬(φ1 ∨ φ2): do return NNF(¬φ1 ∧ ¬φ2);
    otherwise do assert(0);`

How to implement these in C? 
I have been trying hard but couldn't code.
Please help.